# How to count data depending on the date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that get that I get the COUNT of a employee 
where execoffice_status =1 and it works:

```
SELECT employeedept, execoffice_status, employee ,COUNT(*) AS 'employeetotal'
    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    GROUP BY execoffice_status, employee,employeedept
```

What I would like to do is get the COUNT depending on the date of execoffice_date
which i have try to do here:

```
SELECT employeedept, execoffice_status, YEAR_cse =YEAR(execoffice_date),employee ,COUNT(*) AS 'employeetotal'
FROM CSEReduxResponses
WHERE execoffice_status = 1
GROUP BY execoffice_status, employee,employeedept,execoffice_date
```

I would like to get it by date which with the new query I wrote doesnt get me the information I would like.
Which is to give me COUNT depending on what year execoffice_date is .What is doing is giving me It doesn't 
even make sense to me.

I created a dummy table , I can't put it on sqlfiddle (don't know any other place else to put it ) because
is not sqlfiddle is not working properly, must be down.

```
 create table CSEReduxResponses (employeedept int, execoffice_status int, employee int, execoffice_date datetime);
    insert into (employeedept , execoffice_status , employee , execoffice_date )
    values (1,1,10,'2014-05-08'),
    (1,1,10,'2014-05-08'),
    (1,1,10,'2014-05-08'),
    (2,2,11,'2014-05-08'),
    (2,2,11,'2015-05-08'),
    (2,2,11,'2015-05-08'),
    (2,2,11,'2015-05-08'),
    (2,2,11,'2015-04-08');
```

From the data above i would like to get

```
employeedept | execoffice_status | employee | totalstars | year_cse
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 1                  | 10      |3          |2014
2            | 1                  | 11      |1           |2014
2            | 1                  | 11      |4           |2015
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Made changes based on new information

```
SELECT employeedept, execoffice_status, employee, COUNT(*) AS 'totalstars', YEAR_cse =YEAR(execoffice_date)
FROM CSEReduxResponses
WHERE execoffice_status = 1
GROUP BY employeedept, execoffice_status, YEAR(execoffice_date), employee
```

Comment: thanks but this get the total for all the year , but i would like the total for each employee

Comment: @user3591637: I've changed the query to produce the results you specified. That means your original attempt was close, but your `GROUP BY` didn't go by year like your `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

If this is not correct you should try to specify more clearly what you want, including sample data and desired results.

```
SELECT execoffice_date, COUNT(*) AS 'employeetotal'
    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    GROUP BY execoffice_date;
```

Comment: sorry i have made some changes